# React Router ignores my PrivateRoute wrapper when navigating using a Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having a strange issue with React Router. My `PrivateRoute` wrapper doesn't do its thing when navigating using a `Link` or `NavLink`.
Essentially I have something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/"><Home /></Route>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/private"><Private /></PrivateRoute>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`PrivateRoute` is just a wrapper around `Route` that checks for authentication.

Now, if I go to */private* by typing it in the address bar, `PrivateRoute` does its job (and redirects to */login*, but that doesn't matter).
However, if I use a `NavLink` in the `Home` component which has `to="/private"`, React Router routes to the private route even if the user is unauthenticated.

Is there any way I can resolve this reasonably? And why does React Router behave like this and doesn't "go through" all the routes in `BrowserRouter` each time you navigate using a `NavLink`?

Comment: what's your PrivateRoute code? Try to change routes order cause Switch renders the first matching Route

Comment: [Here](https://hastebin.com/ixawuzerad.js)'s the exact PrivateRoute code. Routes order is definitely not an issue, since as I mentioned, it works perfectly when I type the URL in the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a quite simple and dumb fix actually.
The problem was that the `PrivateRoute` component didn't "remount" when changing routes using `Link`s *(that is interesting and somehow clever behavior of React Router, I can imagine this improves performance)*.
Meanwhile, typing a URL into the address bar refreshes the entire page, thus "remounting" all components.

Since the logic for checking auth was in `componentDidMount` only, it didn't launch if the component wasn't "remounted", therefore creating my issue.

For any possible future visitors, to fix this problem, just move your auth checking logic from `componentDidMount` somewhere else, and reference it **both** in `componentDidMount` **and** `componentDidUpdate`. Don't forget to check if props actually changed in `componentDidUpdate` — otherwise you'll create an infinite loop — like so:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // You could also use shallowCompare, but that wasn't needed in my case
  if (this.props.requiredPerms !== prevProps.requiredPerms) {
    this.checkAuth(); // method with the logic which was in componentDidMount before
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to add `exact` or `exact="true"` on public Route.
If you don't include `exact="true"`, `<Route path="/">` refers all sub routes starting with `/`.
So `/private` will match `/` route hence it will render `<Home />`  component.

Here is updated code

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/private">
          <Private />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-ardinghelli-ic0t2?file=/src/App.js) is sample code

Comment: This is not the issue. I just forgot to add `exact` in the question, sorry about that.